# Significato di "liquidare"

Tags: word-meaning

Non riesco a cogliere il significato di *liquidare* in questo contesto:

> Ancora oggi in Cina il fatto che la più grave catastrofe alimentare del novecento sia stata una tragedia provocata dall’uomo è tenuto in scarsa considerazione. Nei libri di scuola la carestia è spiegata citando le cattive condizioni meteorologiche e la sfortuna. Su Baidu Baike, l’equivalente cinese di Wikipedia, **è liquidata** come una “battuta d’arresto” sulla via del socialismo. ([Internazionale](https://www.internazionale.it/magazine/2022/05/19/a-corto-di-grano))

Avendo consultato un [dizionario](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/liquidare), penso che il significato possa essere "risolvere", "criticare" o forse anche "vendere a prezzo basso" (se questo può essere inteso come "sminuire, minimizzare").

Gradirei qualche altro esempio di *liquidare* usato in questo significato.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forse in quell'articolo il verbo “liquidare” non è il più pertinente, ma senz'altro il senso che intendevano gli autori (o, in questo caso, i traduttori) era qualcosa di vicino, come dici, a “sminuire, minimizzare” e forse anche a “sbarazzarsi di”, e simile all'accezione 7 del dizionario di De Mauro che citi, “levare di torno qcn., sbarazzarsene” (che però lì è riferito solo alle persone).

Cercando in rete, si trovano vari esempi in cui qualcuno è accusato di “liquidare una questione” con una battuta, o simili. Per esempio:

> Panino batte mensa però è un modo troppo semplice per liquidare una questione che è molto più complessa di quel che a prima vista sembra. ([Fonte](http://www.vita.it/it/article/2016/09/14/nessuna-vittoria-del-panino-meno-mensa-significa-piu-dispersione/140752/))

(Se qualcuno ha accesso all'[articolo su *Die Zeit*](https://www.zeit.de/2022/20/weizen-ukraine-hunger-kenia-senegal-libanon) di cui questo è una traduzione, sarebbe interessante vedere com'era la formulazione originale.)

Comment: Il corrispondente verbo nella versione di *die Zeit* è *abtun*, che pons.de traduce come... liquidare :) (e in inglese come *dismiss*). La frase completa è "[A]uf Baidu Baike, dem chinesischen Pendant zu Wikipedia, wird sie in wenigen Absätzen als "Rückschlag" auf dem Weg zum Sozialismus abgetan."

Comment: Grazie, @DenisNardin! Anche il dizionario di tedesco della Zanichelli, in questo senso, traduce con “liquidare”, ma poi usa anche altri verbi negli esempi (questa faccenda non si sistema con un semplice grazie, liquidare un'obiezione come infondata, sminuire un problema).